# For 陣, how do 'file of troops' semantically appertain to 'short moment of time'?

Tags: etymology

My Chinese is rudimentary, but [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E9%99%A3) doesn't appear to expatiate this semantic shift.

> 「陣」也用作量詞，表示事物經過的時間段。前蜀毛文錫詞〈醉花間〉：「昨夜雨霏霏，臨明寒一陣。偏憶戍樓人，久絕邊庭信。」宋張輯詞《點絳唇‧南浦月》：「來剪蓴絲，江頭一陣鳴蓑雨。孤篷歸路，吹得蘋風暮。」

[image]

*Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 957.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「陣 」can be thought of as "a certain amount"

> 一陣風
> a breeze
>
> 一陣輕煙
> some light smoke or mist
>
> 他們胡鬧了一陣，就離去了
> a certain amount of time
>
> 一陣間 (in Cantonese)
> a short moment

but I think you can say, to a general in a battle, a certain amount of troop, or to him, it is like a flow of battle force (going from right to left, north to south, etc).

Comment: I don't grasp your answer. Can you pls expatiate? What do you mean by "I think you can say, to a general in a battle, a certain amount of troop"? How's this related to 'short moment of time'?

Comment: like, a short burst of time, a burst of wind, vs a burst of battle force